# Bing.com and SQL Server FTS?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Does bing.com use SQL Server Full Text Search feature? If yes, is there some details about how it uses it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a **BIG NO**. Search engines have their own specialized data-structures and ranking engines (based on many parameters of web documents)

You should start reading from the Google paper [The Anatomy of a Large-Scale Hypertextual Web Search Engine](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~backrub/google.html)